# htaccess redirect non-www to www with SSL/HTTPS

Tags: htaccess, apache, https, mod-rewrite

I want a rewrite rule that redirects everything to `https://` **AND** `www`.

For example `http://example.com` should be going to `https://www.example.com`

This is what I have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the solution.

Without [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) (single redirect):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

With [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) (double redirect):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Note that this will result in a double redirect when requesting `http://example.com` (ie. HTTP and non-www), since it will first redirect to HTTPS on the _same host_ (ie. without `www`) and then redirect to `www` as a second redirect. You can correct this by simply reversing these two rules.

Comment: @MrWhite @will you actually want a double redirect on a proper `https://` redirect, especially if you use HSTS. This way, your HSTS preference can be stored by the browser for both your domains and subsequent requests will always default to `https://`

Comment: @xsrf It's still "proper" (and more efficient) to have a single www _and_ HTTPS redirect. It only _needs_ to be kept separate when you are implementing HSTS.

Comment: Both good points from xsrf and MrWhite. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @xsrf I checked the double redirect with https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ and it appears it only redirects http:// > https:// not https://www.

Comment: @Will The _mwl_ `.htaccess` tool does not "follow redirects", so does not make a second request in order to see the second redirect. To see the second redirect (in that tool) you need to manually create a second test with the output of the first.

Answer (score 6):

Your conditions are implicitly AND'd and your second condition will always be true (unless you have other domains), so your current rules will only redirect non-SSL traffic.

You need to `OR` the conditions and negate the `www` (second) condition:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If the `SERVER_PORT` is not 443 (ie. is not HTTPS) *or* the host does not start with `www.` (ie. you are accessing the bare domain) then redirect to the canonical URL.

However, whether this will redirect `https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com` will depend on your security certificate. (Your site needs to be accessible by both www and non-www over SSL for the .htaccess redirect to trigger.)

Answer (score 1):

This will use for both www or non-www
If you try to open link with www then url redirect to https with www

> Example: `http://domain.com` redirect to `https://domain.com`

or If you try to open link with non-www then url redirect to https with non-www

> Example: `http://www.domain.com` redirect to `https://www.domain.com`

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This doesn't handle the non-www to www redirect as stated in the question.

Comment: You can add this line in htaccess  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: Replace `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]` 

by `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: You can _edit_ your answer.