# APEX domain pointing to the right IP address returns 403 while www works

Tags: htaccess

First time using Microsoft Azure.
I'm using Azure App Service for WordPress for my site farminguru.in for which the A records points to the correct IP address mentioned at Networking in Azure.
DNS is at CloudFlare.
www has CNAME pointing to farminguru.azurewebsites.net

This is what's in the server's .htaccess

```
# HTTPS forced by SG-Optimizer
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
# END HTTPS
```

But my APEX domain returns 403. What do I have to do to modify my .htaccess to redirect my APEX to www ?

Comment: What you are asking (to redirect your domain "apex to www") is a [standard non-www to www redirect](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/84757/htaccess-redirect-non-www-to-www-with-ssl-https) that has been answered here many times before (here's [another example](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/85575/non-www-to-www-redirects)). However, I wonder if there is something more to this? What (and why) is generating the 403 response? Is the request even reaching your server instance?

Comment: The A points to the correct IP but the Azure server seems to be running on nginx ? The user nginx is mentioned in ls of /var/www/wordpress but there exists and .htaccess as well.